# Why doesn't "whereis" locate a file?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, filesystem, search

I was looking for a specific file using `whereis` from the command line.

I got a rather useless result, but I then found the exact file I was looking for by manually searching.

I did not make a mistake in the command line. Why didn't whereis turn up all my files? Is there another method?

Comment: find / | grep filename

Comment: fair point, but updatedb takes time

Comment: Er, I'm pretty sure he meant that normally you'd type that as "find -name 'filename'"

Comment: Is there another method? - Yes! `which` - if you know your file some where in `$PATH`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`whereis` doesn't locate files, because `whereis` command is not intended to be used for that.

From [`whereis` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/whereis)

`whereis - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command`

> whereis locates source/binary and manuals sections for specified
>   files. The supplied names are first stripped of leading pathname
>   components and any (single) trailing extension of the form .ext, for
>   example, .c. Prefixes of s. resulting from use of source code control
>   are also dealt with. whereis then attempts to locate the desired
>   program in a list of standard Linux places.

For more information type `man whereis` in your terminal to refer the `man` page. For finding a file you have to use commands like `grep`, `find`, `locate`, etc...

Comment: @Web-E, Thanks for adding that link.

Answer (score 4):

What you're probably looking for is locate.

The locate man page:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/locate.findutils.1.html

Ubuntu's Community Help Wiki has an entry for finding files. Check it out here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles

Comment: +1 for understanding what he was really asking. :)